# Argument parsing with python decorators

Tags: python

I was wondering if it's possible to wrap some class methods with a decorator that parses the arguments before sending it to the function. for example:

```
    class integer(int):
        def __init__(self, value=0)
            self.value = value
            for m in ['__add__','__sub__','__mul__']:#and so on
                method = getattr(self, m)
                method = magic_decorator(method)
        ...
```

given that **magic_decorator** would be a class or function that captures the single argument from these methods and parse than, for example if it would be a string, instead of letting it in to throw an exception, try to parse as a integer with **int** first.

That would be great for creating even more pythonic types from the native ones.
If it's not possible to do in this stylish way, I would have to override each one doing a repetitive job on each one, which wouldn't be pythonic.

EDIT:
"string"-object or integer-object wouldn't work even so, i would love to know how do I work around this. =]

I didn't a exhaustive search for duplicates, but I'm quite sure that isn't one 'cause my question is a little bit too specific.

Sorry for my bad English, I hope you understand, thanks in advance.

Comment: I really, really doubt very many people would consider this a Pythonic thing to do.

Comment: If you override an immutable type like that you should define `__new__` method, not necessarily `__init__`.

Comment: Keith, I suspected that, i'm working on it, my primary problem now is to make the arithmetic methods work for int-object as well, and since i cannot change int.__add__ methods and so it becomes shady, i feel like i'm missing something very very easy here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Just overwrite every method.
But be careful, decorators are slowing things dowwwwn.

You can just overwrite every method:

```
class new_integer(int):
  __add__ = magic_decorator(int.__add__)
  __sub__ = magic_decorator(int.__sub__)
  ...
```

Or you can do it the easy way:

```
class new_integer(int):
  to_decorate = ( '__add__', '__sub__', ...)
  for k in to_decorate:
    locals()[k] = magic_decorator(getattr(int, k))

  del to_decorate, k
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, it worked for object-int statements, but for int-object statements not, why is that?

Comment: Even if you overwrite the built-in 'int' class with your own, the Python parser won't make hardcoded integers instances of your class. I don't think there is a way to reach this, you really need to define every of your 'new' integers like this: *i = new_integer(2938)*

Answer (score 2):

```
def magic_decorator(method):
    def fun(self, arg):
        if (type(arg) == str):
            arg = int(arg)
        return getattr(int, method)(self, arg)
    return fun

class integer(int):
    pass

for m in ['__add__','__sub__','__mul__']:
    setattr(integer, m, magic_decorator(m))

i = integer(5)
i + "5"
```

Note: if you want the result to be `integer`, use:

```
return integer(getattr(int, method)(self, arg))
```

Comment: It works too yi_H, but same behavior as Niklas answer, works for object-int but not for int-object. thanks.

Comment: you mean `"5" - i`? the string will receive that message, so it won't work.

Comment: yes, and 5 - i too, the int will receive the message, as i suspected, how do i work around this?

Comment: what do you mean with "wrap everything?", and about the upvote, I would love to, and I certainly will, once i get enough reputation points. =]

Comment: use a wrapper class for everything, that's the only way to do it. Also be aware that even if it would work (it won't) `"5" + i` is ambiguous, should that add the numbers or concatenate i to the string?

Comment: Yes I see, i guess it's a design flaw of mine, but thanks anyway, I'll keep this question noted so you'll have your upvote since i got those 15 points!, cya!